# Ошибка при использование команды fin.open() и getline

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Пытаюсь открыть файл, который находится на диске С, но выдает ошибки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()

{
ifstream fin("C:\\Test.txt");
if(fin.good()){
    fin.open ("C:\\Test.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
}else{
cout<<"No"<<endl;
}


if(!fin.is_open()){
    cout<<"First try"<<endl;
}else{
  cout<< "Opened!"<< endl;

  string str="abs";
  while(!fin.eof()){
    str=" ";
    getline(str)
    cout<<str<<endl;
  }

}

fin.clear();

return 0;
}
```

Я изменил строчку где fin.open(...), но раньше было так и IDE ругалось

```
string path= "Test.txt";
ifstream fin;

if(fin.good()){
    fin.open (path);-->no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char> :: open(std::string&)'
}else{
cout<<"No"<<endl;
}
```

А вот какую ошибку выдает с строчкой где getline

```
  string str="abs";
      while(!fin.eof()){
        str=" ";
        getline(str);-->no mathcing function for call to 'getline(std::string&)'
        cout<<str<<endl;
      }
```

Как исправить ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так у вас ошибки при компиляции, а не при открытии файла :)

Просто смотрите описание функций, и все получится...

```
fin.open(path.c_str());
```

потому что ему нужна C-строка

```
getline(str);
```

тут вы вообще просто забыли указать, откуда читать. Ну откуда компилятору это знать? Укажите

```
getline(fin,str);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, я делал по видео уроку, но так почему-то все работало

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - отмечайте как принятый :)

Comment: Да, сейчас отмечу, тут ограничение принятие по времени, через 3 минуту отмечу